# CSS Grid within grid on own line i.e. CSS question

Tags: css, css-grid

I have an application for designing forms that uses Reactive Forms. Simple forms now work perfectly (I am using CSS Grid to display the form). Each row is 12 elements wide but I am having problems displaying grid data correctly i.e. when the user can enter more than one line of data. The "designer" defines a grid in JSON, this is then loaded and the user then enters data into the grid. The designer could design a grid like the one below i.e. one row containing 3 grids. The user would then enter 10 rows entering data into the different grids. The data entry etc works perfectly - where I am having problems is with the alignment of the rows.

I am having problems keeping the elements together when the user adds a new line. I would like to displaying them over two/three lines i.e. I would like to display the blue elements on its own line (maybe indented a bit), the yellow below this (also indented to the blue line). When the user adds another row it should start at the left again - difficult to explain so maybe this will help:

[image]

NB: this is not responsive as it is only used on desktops. Basically I just want to keep the three grids together!

Here is an example of what I get once I have processed the JSON file. I would love some help with the CSS to get the row element correct i.e. the rows always stay together, the grids-in-grid move to the next line.

I have left the creating of new rows out of the code as it is not pertinent - you can just image a + sign to add another row - I do not know in advance how many rows a user will want!

```css
body{
    background: red;
}

.main {
  background-color: blue;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

.input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="main" style="background-color:green;">
      <input id="field1" class="input" type="text" />
      <input id="field1" class="input" type="text" />

      <div class="row" style="background-color:blue; grid-column: span 6;">
        <input id="field1" class="input" type="text" />
        <input id="field1" class="input" type="text" />
        <div class="row"style="background-color:yellow; grid-column: span 6;">
          <input id="field1" class="input" type="text" />
          <input id="field1" class="input" type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think you're going to get there with just this HTML, how much of the nesting can you change? `subgrid` is along the lines of what you are looking for however support is minimal right now, and I don't think it will do everything that you are looking for either.

Comment: I do not know how much nesting there will be as the designer of the form decides that!

Comment: I'll take a look into subgrids - thank you for the pointer